# fetch value corresponding textbox value into select box using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to fetch the value corresponding to textbox value and the results from database show to the select box.

For eg: in a textbox i have entered "abc" now i want whatever database having abc related information come to select box.

Comment: what have you done till now?

Comment: i have done till fetch the value after pressing the button , i want without click results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `autcomplete` functionality. You can use [select2](https://select2.github.io) or something similar.

Comment: This has to be a part of comment!